# NSString isEqaulToString doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

Comparing NSString with a string literal doesn't work.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/sw_vers"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-productVersion"]];

NSPipe * out = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:out];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSFileHandle * read = [out fileHandleForReading];
NSData * dataRead = [read readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString * actualOSVersion = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", actualOSVersion);

if ([actualOSVersion isEqualToString:@"10.8.5"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", actualOSVersion);
}
```

> NSLog(@"%@", actualOSVersion); prints 10.8.5 but if statement is always false.

When i compare NSString *temp = @"10.8.5" with string literal @"10.8.5" it always returns true.Can anyone help me to understand the problem.

Comment: What is the value in temp? There is no code block where temp variable assigned to any value.

Comment: Check if actualOSVersion has empty space at the beginning or end.

Comment: Use this:  if ([[actualOSVersion stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString: @"10.8.5"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that there are more characters in actualOSVersion, including spaces or newline characters.

Put quotes in the format string so you can see whitespace characters in the result.

Or "trim" the string variable before comparing it with isEqualToString.

Comment: Thanks @Walt Sellers for pointing out this issue, actually actualOSVersion contains new line character at the end. Now [[actualOSVersion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""] isEqualToString:@"10.8.5"] returns true.

Comment: @akhilshrivastav: I wouldn't do the "replace" thing, trimming is what one usually does here as Walt suggested.

Comment: @DarkDust Thanks for suggestion. for testing purpose I used "replace" thing.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the command has an additional newline at the end. So the string in `actualOSVersion` is equal to `@"10.8.5\n"`. You need to trim it, e.g.:

```
actualOSVersion = [actualOSVersion stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your log statement to:

```
NSLog(@"\"%@\"", actualOSVersion);
```

That way, the outputted string will be surrounded by "" and you'll be able to see if there's any extra characters like space or newline in it.